# Removing an Modx extra manually

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks

I have installed a few extras via Installer but removed them later. However, Installer has not been able to remove them successfully. For example, site log is now full of error messages of partially installed/removed extras.

How could I remove manually all traces of these extras? Where is the data stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the value {locator":{"path":"[[++core_path]]components/locator/model/"} from extension_packages system setting helped.

Thanks @anton-tarasow.

Answer (score 1):

Usually extras store files into two folders (I assume you have basic MODX settings):
/assets/components/{yourExtraAliasName} and /core/components/{yourExtraAliasName}

Also please read carefully your log, maybe some snippet calls still exist somewhere in chunks/templates/snippets/TVs, you should find and remove them too.

After all, it'll good to clear MODX cache as well.

Comment: Thanks for good advises.

For example, this is one of the log line:

[2021-02-28 12:28:58] (ERROR @ /home/xxxxxx/domains/xxxxx/public_html/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 503) Path specified for package locator is not a valid or accessible directory: /home/xxxx/domains/xxxxxx/public_html/core/components/locator/model/

I think that is related to "locator" extra that I have removed. No folders exist but some part of the site still tries to use it? This line is repeated in the log all the time.

Comment: Hi! Quite old package...I've installed it and right after deinstalled & removed package. I've got the same message: Path specified for package locator is not a valid or accessible directory: /www/core/components/locator/model/ What you should for fix: please find extension_packages system setting and remove next value part: ,{"locator":{"path":"[[++core_path]]components\/locator\/model\/"}} This will help!

Comment: @anton-tarasow, thanks a lot. I will do this.